# Is there an antonym of 'Talisman'

Tags: single-word-requests

For example "The watch was a ____, it brought me nothing but bad luck"

Using the definition "Something **worn** that gives good luck" the Antonyms suggested by Mirriam-Webster (Hoodoo and Jinx) don't seem to quite fit the bill.

A composite or a metaphor would work too.. Is there something like a rabbits foot that is said to bring bad luck?

Comment: Sounds like a voodoo pin, but jinx is good, that is, bad.

Comment: Since this isn't SO, we leave a `___` or `X` where we want the word!

Comment: I see 'Jinx' as a curse, not a cursed item.

Comment: [Bad mojo](https://www.gog.com/game/bad_mojo_redux)?

Comment: Does a **cursed item** work?

Comment: I like "monkey's paw", but that may be quite a bit stronger than you need.  Otherwise, something like "trouble magnet" seems decent.

Comment: @davo "Cursed item" sounds a bit stilted to my ears… "Curse" on its own is fine as a noun though — "The watch was a curse, it brought me nothing but bad luck"

Comment: That cracked mirror that I carry around in my back pocket. :-)

Comment: *bad luck charm*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know it was already brought up in a comment, but jinx has a definition as a noun:

**Jinx**

> [(dictionary.com)](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/jinx): *noun*, 1. a person, thing, or influence supposed to bring bad luck.
>
> [(M-W)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jinx): *noun*, one that brings bad luck;
>
> *"That guy is a jinx."*

The use in the supplied sentence works fine:

> The watch was a ***jinx***, it brought me nothing but bad luck.

Comment: Or if you insist a *jinx* is a curse and not a cursed item, you can always say "The watch was jinxed,..."